# Substring in Calc script Essbase

Tags: oracle, hyperion, essbase

I am trying to get the First 3 characters from Accounts dimension in Essbase (BSO cube). When i try to execute the below query. I am getting an error "Invalid Object type"

```
FIX(
@substring(@NAME("Account"),0,3),
"Jan"
)
ENDFIX
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to obtain? 
In the FIX section you should only write the cross-members for the calc

like

```
FIX("Jan", "FY20", "Actual")
/*In this section you can include the code*/
@CONCATENATE("Item_",@substring(@NAME("Account"),0,3))  
ENDFIX
```